# Can not insert More than 53 Records in Mysql database laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to import data from Excel file to MySQL database, anyway when the file contains for example 100 Records it seems just only 53 records can be imported, I don't understand why, and from where I can extend this number if it is already configured.

and even when the file contains 54 records it just imports 53.
it seems to be like fixed number
this is my code which will receive  data from excel file and insert it in to database

```
$question_bank_id = $request->input('question_bank');
$tempQuestion = array();
foreach ($request["all_questions"] as $key => $value){

    $request["all_questions"] = array($key => $value);
    Var_dump($request["all_questions"]);
    $$module_name_singular = $module_model::create($request->except('question_bank','earn_list'));
    $$module_name_singular->earn()->attach($request->input('earn_list'));

    array_push($tempQuestion,$$module_name_singular->id);
}
```

thank you

Comment: Yes you could insert Millions if you wanted to. So you had better show us your code, and your data, and have a close look at the error log and show us any errors from that also

Answer (score 1):

Do you not see you are over writing the variable that you are looping on??

```
$question_bank_id = $request->input('question_bank');
$tempQuestion = array();
foreach ($request["all_questions"] as $key => $value){

    // This next line destroys $request["all_questions"]
    // which is the variable you are looping over
    $request["all_questions"] = array($key => $value);

    Var_dump($request["all_questions"]);

    // next 3 line has `$$` and I dont think you ment to
    $$module_name_singular = $module_model::create($request->except('question_bank','earn_list'));

    $$module_name_singular->earn()->attach($request->input('earn_list'));

    array_push($tempQuestion,$$module_name_singular->id);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply , but even when I removing $request["all_questions"] = array($key => $value);  it is still 53 records

Comment: I noticed that the array  $request["all_questions"] not holding all data , it holding only 53 element , I don't understand , is it related to memory ?

Comment: Then you will have to look at how that is filled! Or show us in another question